# arDetectMarker + pixel format + segmentation fault

Tags: c

I am trying to use the arDetectMarker function from arToolKit to detect markers in an image. I read the image from disk in the following way:

```
cv::Mat image;
cv::Mat temp;
image = cv::imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv::cvtColor(image, temp, CV_RGB2BGR);
```

and converted to ARUint8* format using:

```
dataPtr = (ARUint8 *) ((IplImage) temp).imageData;
```

I am sure that the data is correctly converted to dataPtr since I saved the image to check. Unfortunately, when I call arDetectMarker, a "segmentation fault" happens and I don't know the reason (I think it is due to the pixel format). I've read in the documentation:

http://artoolkit.sourceforge.net/apidoc/ar_8h.html#b2868d9587c68fb7255d4f270bcf878f

and it says that the format is in general ABGR. But I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I think that I have v4l drivers, although I am not sure since I am not working with videos. I tried to convert the image loaded to ABGR or BGRA, but I am not sure if I did it correctly, or if this is really a requirement.

Also, I did the calibration procedure before.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks!

Marcelo.